# how to move double tall div from left to between right divs on screen shrink?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a section with three divs; A large one on the left for a textarea and two normal sized ones on the left for some info and some buttons. The only problem is when the page shrinks I would like the textarea to be between the other two divs.

I've tried playing with different sized divs, variations on push and pull from bootstrap, overwriting float and a few other style parameters.

I made a Pen with two examples, one that works when the screen is small and another that works when the screen is large.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZgXWwX?editors=1100

```
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The head section ^ is what bootstrap/jquery version I was using for the test

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <br/>
  <p>Correct when screen is small (incorrect when large):</p>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6" style="background-color:green;">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;">1st div</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgray;">also 1st div</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
        large div 
        <br/>
      large div 
    </div>

      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        3rd div
    </div>

  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <p>Correct when screen is large (incorrect when small):</p>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
        lav 
        <br/>
      lav
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:green;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;">cy</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgray;">grey</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      3rd div
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body
```

The "1st" div is broken into two pieces because that is what I plan to use and it needs to not be broken.

Using push and pull puts the 3rd div on the bottom left instead of the right next to the larger div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a mockup or wireframe of what you are trying to achieve on a large screen and a small screen? I'm having some trouble following. One thing that I would like to note, regardless, though, is that Bootstrap layouts are based on rows (top to bottom, with content divided therein), so if your predominant goal with your content is to arrange it from left to right, it might be tricky. I only mention this because it looks like you might want the large lavender div to run down into the next row to fill in the space to the left of the blush div. If that's the case, grid might be a better choice. [Here's a quick pen](https://codepen.io/anna-gallo/pen/wVrJam).

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="Lavender"><br>This is my lavender content.</div>
  <div class="Cyan"><br>This is my cyan content.</div>
  <div class="Grey"><br>This is my grey content.</div>
  <div class="Blush"><br>This is my blush content.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body,
.grid-container {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container * {
  position: relative;
}

.grid-container *:after {
  content: attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "Lavender Lavender Cyan Grey" "Lavender Lavender Blush Blush" ". . . .";
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "Cyan Cyan Cyan Cyan" "Grey Grey Grey Grey" "Lavender Lavender Lavender Lavender" "Blush Blush Blush Blush";
  }
}

.Lavender {
  grid-area: Lavender;
  background-color: lavender;
}

.Cyan {
  grid-area: Cyan;
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

.Grey {
  grid-area: Grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.Blush {
  grid-area: Blush;
  background-color: lavenderblush;
}
```